# Why would an image look the same pre-raytracing and post-raytracing?

Tags: raytracing

I am trying to raytrace an image of a black hole, but given my current difficulties of doing so with the formalism of relativity, I've decided to do my raytracing using Newton's law of gravitation instead:

```
a = -GM / r^2
```

This is my code so far:

```python
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

M = 500.0
max_iterations = 100
dt = 0.1

img_width = 160
img_height = 90
resolution = (img_width, img_height)
sensor_width = 0.035
focal_length = 0.025
camera_origin = np.array([0, 7 * M, 0])

def norm(x):
    return (x.dot(x)) ** (1/2)

def normalize(x):
    return x / norm(x)

class Camera:
    def __init__(self, pos=camera_origin, resolution=resolution, sensor_width=sensor_width, focal_length=focal_length, z_rotation=np.pi / 4):
        rot_z = np.array([
                    [np.cos(z_rotation), -np.sin(z_rotation), 0],
                    [np.sin(z_rotation), np.cos(z_rotation), 0],
                    [0, 0, 1]
                ])
        self.rot_matrix = rot_z
        self.pos = np.matmul(rot_z, pos)
        self.resolution = resolution
        self.sensor_width = sensor_width
        self.focal_length = focal_length
    
    def ray_vel(self, i, j):
        w, h = self.resolution
        aspect_ratio = w / h
        # The u and v vectors are
        # the vectors of the camera
        # viewport
        u = self.sensor_width
        v = -self.sensor_width / aspect_ratio
        du = u / w
        dv = v / h
        # Find the directional vector
        # of a ray that passes through
        # a given pixel
        x = -u/2 + (i + 1) * du
        y = self.focal_length
        z = -v/2 + (j + 1) * dv
        pixel_dir = np.array([x, y, z])
        # Rotate the directional vector about
        # the z-axis with given amount
        pixel_dir = np.matmul(self.rot_matrix, pixel_dir)
        # Make these unit vectors
        # as speed of light in geometrized
        # units is 1
        return normalize(pixel_dir)

class Ray:
    def __init__(self, origin, direction):
        self.origin = origin
        self.direction = direction

    def compute(self, t):
        pos = self.origin
        vels = self.direction
        # Use Euler's method to
        # numerically solve
        # the differential equation
        # a = -GM/r^2
        for i in range(t):
            r = norm(pos)
            vels -= M / (r ** 2) * dt
            pos += vels * dt
        return vels

    def trace(self, tmax=100):
        ray_dir = self.compute(tmax)
        v_x, v_y, v_z = normalize(ray_dir)
        color_r = int(abs(v_x) * 255)
        color_g = int(abs(v_y) * 255)
        color_b = int(abs(v_z) * 255)
        return (color_r, color_g, color_b)

bh_img = Image.new("RGB", (img_width, img_height))
counter = 0
camera = Camera()

print("Beginning raytracing...")
for i in range(0, img_width):
    for j in range(0, img_height):
        ray_origin = camera.pos
        ray_dir = camera.ray_vel(i, j)
        ray = Ray(ray_origin, ray_dir)
        color = ray.trace(max_iterations)
        bh_img.putpixel((i, j), color)
        if counter % 1000 == 0:
            print(f"Computed ray {counter} of {img_width * img_height}")
        counter += 1

bh_img.save("render_output.jpg")
```

My code essentially emits rays from the camera, computes their trajectories as they orbit around the black hole, and then finds their final direction, which I have outputted as an RGB color for debugging purposes. What is bizarre to me is that regardless of the values of `M` I use, the raytraced image looked exactly as if I just outputted the initial ray direction. There is seemingly no change in ray direction as the rays are traced around the black hole. Is there any reason why this is?